# How to define any text and page number in header?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I use the following code to have a customized header in all pages, but I've lost the page numbering:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{\textbf{DOCUMENT TITLE}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=0.5pt

\fancyhf{}

\lhead{\small{DOCUMENT}}
\thispagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{TITLE}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the page number, you must use `\thepage`.

For example, put the following line:

```
\rhead{\small{\thepage}}
```

in the preamble of your document, to get that number at the right side of the header.